# Can FieldNameToFieldConstant be used with the TaskDependency Object

Tags: vba, ms-project

I am using the TaskDependency Object to Trace Predecessors for a Target Task. I then want to update one of the "Number" fields with the value of the current link pair.  I increment this value as I traverse down each link in the trace. I use this Number field as a sort field so the trace can be presented in logic order and not Task ID order

I want to make this Number field to be ANY available Number field, identified with a Custom Name so it is a Custom field.  I have experimented with .Getfield and .SetField to read and write this incremented number.

I have a subroutine that examines all Number fields for the Custom Name I have associated with this procedure. I named this procedure  CustomNumberNameExists, and this function returns a string, such as Number18, if Number18 has the Custom Name "MarkedPred" It also returns the 9 character field identifier "C", ie 188743994 for field Number18.

The Subroutine to identify which Number field has been customized with the MarkedPred custom name:

```
enter code here

    For i = 1 to 20
         if (CustomFieldGetName(C) = "MarkedPred") Then
             fldMarkedPred = "Number" & i
             MarkedPred_Method = C
         End If
    next i
```

The Subroutine to trace the network backwards given a single target task:

```
enter code here

    Sub DepPredNew(Tsk As Task)

    Dim Dep As TaskDependency    
    Dim SumT As Task    
    Dim SubT As Task    

   'First Section processes for PredSelAll = False  = Only Incomplete tasks 

   If PredSelAll = False Then                                                                              
        If (Tsk.Marked = False) Then
             Tsk.Marked = True

   'exclude links to external tasks                                                                   
        For Each Dep In Tsk.TaskDependencies                                          
            If (Dep.From.ExternalTask = True) Then                            
                Debug.Print ("found Dep.From.ExternalTask= " & Dep.From.ExternalTask)                         
                GoTo NextOne
            End If

            If ((Dep.From.ID <> Tsk.ID) And (Dep.From.PercentComplete <> 100)) Then
               Projectfield = FieldNameToFieldConstant("MarkedPred")
                    If (Dep.From.Number18 = 0) Then  'And (Dep.From.Predecessors <> "")) Then
                        LogicOrder = LogicOrder + 1
                        Dep.From.Number18 = LogicOrder
                        Tsk.Marked = True
                    End If
                    DepPredNew Dep.From   
    NextOne:

        End If
    Next Dep
End If
```

All of the above routines work as desired except they are hardcoded to use Number18 field.
I would like to replace all instances of .Number18 with "MarkedPred", making this subroutine flexible such that ANY number field that is available can be customized with the custom name - MarkedPred.
I am trying to use Projectfield, such as Dep.From.Projectfield instead of using Dep.From.Number18.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is exactly what [GetField](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.task.getfield) and [SetField](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.task.setfield) are for.

Change `Dep.From.Number18` to `Dep.From.GetField(Projectfield)` and `Dep.From.SetField(Projectfield)`.

FYI: move `Projectfield = FieldNameToFieldConstant("MarkedPred")` to outside the loop since it only needs to be calculated once. Even better would be to move it outside this recursive procedure and make it a module-level variable; otherwise it's still getting called for every task.

Comment: Thank you, Rachel.  This is exactly what I was looking for.  Had tried using Setfield and getfield but previously without success. Now I cna make my app completely independent of any particular field but rather can simple use a Custom Name to identify a field.