# How to retrieve the Custom Text (Assignment) Field value based on a Custom Number value in MS Project VBA?

Tags: vba, ms-project

I can get to the values I am after by hardcoding, for example *assignment.Text8* but can't get it to work when I create a variable and try to include it like: "if **i** = 8 then show me what is in assignment.Text**i**"
Could be a syntax thing but can't figure it out.

```
Sub TransferAsgnTextX_to_AsgnTCC_viaNumberedMeans()
Dim t As Task
Dim a As Assignment
Dim nr, i As Integer
i = 1
For Each t In ActiveProject.Tasks
    nr = ActiveProject.Tasks(i).Number1
    If nr > 0 Then
    For Each a In t.Assignments
        Select Case a.ResourceName
        Case "Productivity"
            a.Units = "a.Text" & nr
        End Select
    Next a
    End If
    i = i + 1
Next t
End Sub
```

Above code gives a run-time error 1101, but if I hardcoded say *a.Units = a.Text8* then the code runs. But I want to find the custom text field based on the (separate) custom number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The MS Project API doesn't have a good way to do what you are trying to do for *Assignments* (it does for Tasks and Resources), so I would recommend creating a function that you can call whenever you want to get the data:

```
Public Function GetAssignmentTextInfo(a As Assignment, fieldNumber As Integer) As String

If fieldNumber = 1 Then
    GetAssignmentTextInfo = a.Text1
End If

If fieldNumber = 2 Then
    GetAssignmentTextInfo = a.Text2
End If

If fieldNumber = 3 Then
    GetAssignmentTextInfo = a.Text3
End If

If fieldNumber = 4 Then
    GetAssignmentTextInfo = a.Text4
End If

'... so on through 30 (for the 30 text fields)
```

Now you could just call this in your code block:

```
Sub TransferAsgnTextX_to_AsgnTCC_viaNumberedMeans()

    Dim t As Task
    Dim a As Assignment
    Dim nr, i As Integer
    i = 1
    
    For Each t In ActiveProject.Tasks
        nr = ActiveProject.Tasks(i).Number1
        If nr > 0 Then
            For Each a In t.Assignments
                Select Case a.ResourceName
                Case "Productivity"
                    'call our function instead of hard coding
                    a.Units = GetAssignmentTextInfo(a, i) & nr
                End Select
            Next a
        End If
        i = i + 1
    Next t
    
End Sub
```

As an added bonus to enhance the method, you could create an Enum called "FieldType" or something like that and include that as an argument in the GetAssignmentTextInfo function so it could retrieve data from other fields aside from just Text1-30.

```
Public Enum FieldType
    Text = 1
    Number = 2
    Flag = 3
    OutlineCode = 4
    'etc...
End Enum

Public Function GetAssignmentInfo(a As Assignment, fieldNumber As Integer, fType As FieldType) As String
    
    If fType = FieldType.Text Then
        If fieldNumber = 1 Then
            GetAssignmentTextInfo = a.Text1
        End If
        
        If fieldNumber = 2 Then
            GetAssignmentTextInfo = a.Text2
        End If
        
        '... so on through 30 (for the 30 text fields)
    End If
    
    If fType = FieldType.Number Then
        If fieldNumber = 1 Then
            GetAssignmentTextInfo = CStr(a.Number1)
        End If
        
        If fieldNumber = 2 Then
            GetAssignmentTextInfo = CStr(a.Number2)
        End If
        
        '... so on through 20 (for the 20 number fields)
    End If
```

Comment: Thankyou Kenny, that's fantastic. It works according to my intentions with the slight modification to one line when calling the function:            a.Units = GetAssignmentTextInfo(a, nr)            Also replacing your "fieldnumber" with my "nr" in the Public Function.          I have the added bonus Enum working as well, so thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Stephen, if I follow what you are trying to do, you want to change the assignment units for the "Productivity" resource to whatever value is in the Task Number1 field. If so then just do that, i.e.
a.Units = nr

Comment: Hi John (bona-vide guru!)

Comment: No, trying something a bit more complex. If I have a few "Productivity" options stored in one or all of the Text Fields (1-30) at the assignment level, then I want the macro to update the a.Units according to what is in the Text Field corresponding to the user's selected task.Number1

Comment: spell check ^bona-fide

Comment: Stephen, yeah, after I re-read your question I realized I was missing the point. I seem to recall figuring out how to do what you want some years back but it escapes me now. However I do have a brute force approach. Create a sub that is a Case statement that selects one of the 30 Assignment Text fields depending on the value in Task Number 1 field. A little crude, but it will get you there.

Comment: Thanks John, was hoping to avoid that approach but am happy with crude if that's what works!  I won't say the question is answered yet, just in case you remember or someone else might be able to add a touch of elegance to my hacky code.

Comment: Stephen, "hacky code", well that's one way to look at it but I prefer to view it as a solution to a problem. When no direct approach is available I look for "end around run" type solutions.

Comment: yes I think we are in furious agreement. I guess I have learnt just enough to be surprised that it takes 30 select cases for the above, yet it takes about 1 line of code to drill down into any outlinecode entry I need, eg. ActiveProject.OutlineCodes.Item(i).LookupTable.Item(j).Description

Answer (score 0):

For the [Assignment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.assignment) object, there is no way around getting properties other than accessing them directly. So the solution is to use a Select Case statement.

FWIW this would be much simpler if the values were stored at the task level as the [Task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.task) object offers the [GetField](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.task.getfield) method that takes a field ID parameter and returns the variable field value. See [I can't access columns in MS Project VSTO Add-In](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70570565/i-cant-access-columns-in-ms-project-vsto-add-in/70572466#70572466) and [Can FieldNameToFieldConstant be used with the TaskDependency Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59972114/can-fieldnametofieldconstant-be-used-with-the-taskdependency-object) for examples.

Comment: Hi Rachel, Wow, two all-time #msproject #VBA legends taking the time to look at my question, much appreciated! Actually, my concept needs the values stored at the assignment level. All part of my cunning plan to reveal #msproject as the next killer app by helping everyone to solve their *Time-Cost Problem*(s) :)

Comment: @StephenRichards sounds great! The more you work with the object model the more you'll find shortcomings like the fact that GetField exists for the task object but not assignments. It's not as robust as the Excel model but nevertheless amazing things can be done. Good luck.